# Javascript placing element on coordinates / percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am developing a smart phone app and I am trying to place a 'note' or a 'marker' over an image. I have not got a potential solution for this, I am starting out new with this sorta thing.

I am using http://www.icenium.com/ for the app distribution.

Is it possible to tap / click somewhere and add an element (div) to be always at that point on the image with javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Any advancements on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function point_it(event){
                pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
                pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
                document.getElementById("imgcr").style.left = (pos_x-7)+"px" ;
                document.getElementById("imgcr").style.top = (pos_y-8)+"px" ;
                document.getElementById("imgcr").style.visibility = "visible" ;
                document.pointform.form_x.value = pos_x;
                document.pointform.form_y.value = pos_y;
            }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="pointform" method="post">
        <div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" style = "background-image:url('http://www.woofers.net/communities/6/004/008/640/226/images/4555331877.jpg');width:500px;height:333px;">
        <img src="http://galeriejeanclaudebergeron.ca/images/redDot.png" id="imgcr" style="position:relative;visibility:hidden;z-index:2;"></div>
        You pointed on x = <input type="text" name="form_x" size="4" /> - y = <input type="text" name="form_y" size="4" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy paste this into a new file and open it on your browser. In this example I move a div to the position, but you'll have to clone it if you want multiple points

Try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7RCA/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that would all just be down to relative and absolute positioning of elements. You then need to loop through all the images and get variables for the image width and height, and then find the top positioning of the image. You can then use all this to position you "note" when you click the button.

Here is the JS Fiddle, it should explain better - http://jsfiddle.net/davemcmillan/6cEEy/

The width and height if the image need to be in the image tag.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want some kind of tooltip to be put in an exact place where user clicks. Here's a simple example of how to do that using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/QDJGc/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to store the data (in a database) so when you reload the page they are in the same place? Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is, but not with javascript alone. Depending on what you need, you can use AJAX to send data to your server side application which can store it in a database and then use it to generate HTML after page reload; or you can use cookies if you need to store data for the longer periods of time for each user. There other possibilities, but these two are probably most useful.